# how to compile a VC project using g++?

Tags: c++, linux, g++

i have source code of vc++ project. Now I am using linux.
i know how compile a single file .cpp not a whole project. So how to compile a VC project using g++ ?

Comment: Find a good tutorial on Makefiles.

Comment: Or even better: take a look at a modern tool like [SConstruct](http://www.scons.org/)

Comment: are you looking for compiling only, or the whole set of build tools, including linker, resource editor, etc? what kind of VC++ project is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slight advantage of Makefiles would be possible integration with autotools (*cough* - It *might* prove handy to get the starting point for feature macros).[2]

There is a tool as part of [winemaker](http://www.winehq.org/docs/winemaker) that is EXCEEDINGLY helpful with fixing up a source tree that was assuming case insensitive names to work on a case-sensitive filesystem. (_it was intended mainly in order to build against winelib but that is not required)

If you want to keep using windows API's for some parts of the code, you can consider compiling with winelib (and use winegcc, producing WIN32 executables; I'm not sure whether this is what you want)

[2]:  SCons is a very nice tool though

Comment: Seconding the scons recommendation. I had a small project set up with it once.

Answer (score 0):

First step would be to generate Makefile out of vcproj file.
There are (obviously) some tools for that:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cross-platform/sln2mak.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do it. As others have suggested you can figure out how the build process works for this project (maybe by reading the build output in VS) and recreate that using your favorite linux build tool (scons, cmake, autotools etc.). The alternative is to use a converter tool. Aside from the below mentioned sln2mak, there is also winemaker. The docs for winemaker have a lot of old info like most linux tools docs but it can convert a .sln to a makefile. I am not sure about newer vs .sln files.